# Do different fishing holes have different odds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I am wondering if different fishing holes have different odds distributions? For example, do some have increased odds of yielding gunny sacks compared to the average? Or do some yield rare fish more often?

I was wondering this because some fishing holes are hard to fish from whereas others are easy. For example, in Wrothgar, Nikolvara’s Kennel there are 4 fishing holes in a row. The 2 on the north end of the stream are easy because there are no obstacles. The ones on the south end of the stream are guarded by durzogs. I was thinking maybe the guarded ones would yield rare results more often.

I can only accept answers that can back up their assertions with quotes from official documentation, forum posts by official developer team members, reverse engineered code, statistical analysis of extensive fishing or similar.

I am **not** asking about:

- how food or equipment that affects fishing odds
- how only certain fish are in certain kinds of holes.
- how quantity of players fishing same hole affects odds.
- how bait must match water type

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of.  It seems they are are randomly generated.  I have done the fishing achievement on a few different toons and it still took me the same amount of time.  Granted some holes like foul waters in certain zone only have 2-4 holes so you have no choice to fish those for your achievements.  Where as most ocean holes are abundant and have many options but I haven't noticed a difference in drops between holes with or without mobs to kill.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link below, different fishing have different water types.

Depending on which water type you are fishing from you should use different bait. It says that using the right bait for the right water type significantly increases your chance of a fish or rare fish. (the part labeled, fishing holes)

[Here is the site](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Fishing_(Online))

Comment: I applaud your effort to answer questions, but matching bait to water type is well known. I will update my question to exclude that also.